# $T\circ T=0:V\rightarrow V \implies R(T) \subset N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

### Question

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear map. How do I prove that $T \circ T = T_0$ ( the zero linear map) iff $R(T) \subset N(T)$?

### Attempt

\begin{eqnarray}
T\circ T=T(T(v))&=&T(T(v-0))\\
&=&T(T(v)+T(-0))\\
&=&T(T(v))+T(T(-0))\\
&=&T(T(v))+T(-T(0))\\
&=&T(T(v))-T(T(0))&=&0,
\end{eqnarray}
so this last bit gives
\begin{eqnarray}
T(T(v))=T(T(0)),
\end{eqnarray}
which means $T(v)=T(0)=0~\forall~v\in V$, so $R(T)=0$, this zero of which is in the null space for all linear maps $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T\circ T=T_0$$
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$T(T(v))=T_0(v)\qquad\forall v\in V$$
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$T(T(v))=0 \qquad \forall v\in V$$
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$T(v)\subseteq N(T)\qquad \forall v\in V$$
$$\textrm{if and only if}$$
$$R(T)\subseteq N(T)$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T^2=T_0$. Take $x\in R(T)$, so $x=T(v)$ for some $v$. Then $T(x)=T(T(v))=\dots$? How does this show $R(T)\subseteq N(T)$?

Conversely, suppose $R(T)\subseteq N(T)$. Then for any $v\in V$, $T^2(v)=T(T(v))$. Since $T(v)\in R(T)$, what does $T(T(v))$ equal? How does this show $T^2=T_0$?

Comment: ...? $=0$, and $0\in N(T)$ for any linear map, right?

Comment: How does my attempt not suffice?

Comment: @Trancot For one, you don't mention that $T$ is injective, so $T(T(v))=T(T(0))$ doesn't imply $T(v)=T(0)$ for all $v$.

Comment: What do you think of Federica Maggioni's answer?